# Inheritance in Lua

Tags: oop, inheritance, lua

I am trying to make a simple api that eases the process of creating classes and sub-classes.

```
function newClass(index,...)
  local new_class = {}

  setmetatable(new_class,{__index = index})

  local optionalArgs = {...}
  if optionalArgs[1] ~= nil then
      setmetatable(new_class,optionalArgs[1])
  end

  return new_class

end

--TESTINGCODE
exampleSuper = newClass({name="Super",id=1,getName = function() print("Super") end,})
exampleSuper.getName()
exampleSub = newClass({name="Sub",},exampleSuper)
print(exampleSub.id)
```

The problem is that even though I create a new super class called exampleSuper, it's fields aren't given to the exampleSub class. How can I change my code to allow my function to define a sub class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, maybe:

```
function newClass(new_obj,old_obj)
  old_obj = old_obj or {}               --use passed-in object (if any)
  new_obj = new_obj or {}
  assert(type(old_obj) == 'table','Object/Class is not a table')
  assert(type(new_obj) == 'table','Object/Class is not a table')
  old_obj.__index = old_obj             --store __index in parent object (optimization)
  return setmetatable(new_obj,old_obj)  --create 'new_obj' inheriting 'old_obj'
end
```

Answer (score 3):

This question is well answered in [Object-Oriented Programming chapter of Programming In Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/16.html), specifically in the [Inheritance](http://www.lua.org/pil/16.2.html) section.

In your particular case, when `optionalArgs[1] ~= nil` check is true, you don't set `__index` in the metatable as you overwrite your earlier assignment.

Answer (score 1):

In `newClass`, your second call to `setmetatable` simply overwrites the first one. The following shorter function will give you the expected behavior:

```
function newClass(new_class, super)
  new_class = new_class or {}

  -- This assumes single inheritance. Multiple inheritance would require a
  -- function for __index.
  if super then
    setmetatable(new_class,{__index = super})
  end

  return new_class

end
```